# Cannot insert a simple table into Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure what's going on, but I cannot seem to insert a simple row into Postgres. I have a `quotes` table with the following columns (`id`, `quote`, `tags`, `author`) and none are required -- id auto increments.

I try the following `INSERT INTO quotes(quote) VALUES('This is a test')` and I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "This is a test" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO quotes(quote) VALUES ("This is a test");
^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "This is a test" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 36
```

Comment: Interesting! If I directly type the command in the postgres command line, it works, however, within my node environment or with PGAdmin, it gives me the error I mentioned.

Comment: Wait, you're using this INSERT using `pg` in nodejs?

Comment: FYI: what you tried and your error message show two different things.  In your example you use `'...'` but in your error it says you used `"..."` - which is it?

Comment: Here's an example of using the `pg` module in nodejs using variables just incase you need it in the future `client.query('SELECT * FROM agents WHERE email = $1', ['julianguterman@myemail.com'], callback())` the variable place holder `$1` will look for the first item in the array. If you used $2 somewhere else in the query it would look for the 2nd item in the array etc.

Comment: `"This is a test"` is an identifier in SQL `'This is a test'` is a string literal: See the manual for details: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres expects its values as a literal string in single quotes.  Double quotes are used to refer to case-specific entity names, such as schemas, tables, fields, etc.

In your case, Postgres is trying to find a field called "This is a test", I believe from table *quotes*, but it doesn't exist.  Ergo, `'This is a test'`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Postgres. This is how it is specified for the SQL language